Decomposing a matrix as $D_1 S D_2$ where $D_1$ and $D_2$ are positive diagonal and $S$ is nonnegative symmetric
Sinkhorn's theorem gives that every positive square matrix can be factored as $D_1 S D_2$ where $D_1$ and $D_2$ are positive diagonal and $S$ is doubly stochastic.
By analogy:
Which real matrices can be factored as $D_1 S D_2$ where $D_1$ and $D_2$ are positive diagonal and $S$ is nonnegative symmetric? Is is possible that all nonnegative matrices can be factored in this fashion?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

I edited the question.
